# How to create HDFS file with a different owner than the client process

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

The [HDFS Administrator Guide](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.19.0/hdfs_permissions_guide.html) states

> "When a file or directory is created, its owner is the user identity
>   of the client process, and its group is the group of the parent
>   directory (the BSD rule)."

Are there any exceptions to this rule?  Running a process as user 'clientA' is there any way to create a file with a different owner?

I'm running with `hadoop.security.authentication=simple`.  It looks like I can call [`setOwner`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html#setOwner%28org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) after the fact, and that's a perfectly valid fallback solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it look sane??

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, URISyntaxException, InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        conf.addResource(new Path("/hadoop/projects/hadoop-1.0.4/conf/core-site.xml"));
        conf.addResource(new Path("/hadoop/projects/hadoop-1.0.4/conf/hdfs-site.xml"));
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Enter the directory URI...");
        String dirPath = br.readLine();
        URI uri = new URI(dirPath);
        System.out.println("Enter the user...");
        String user = br.readLine();
        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(uri, conf, user);
        fs.mkdirs(new Path(uri.toString()), FsPermission.getDefault());
        FSDataOutputStream fsDataOutputStream = fs.create(new Path(uri.toString()+"/file.txt"));
        fsDataOutputStream.writeBytes("This is a demo file..!!!!");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you want but you can do something like below from a script/process from the current user account to create a file with some other users account in HDFS. But, if your other user has password, you need to manuallay enter the password or find your own way to do the same.

e.g.

```
 su - otherUser -c 'hadoop fs -touchz myfile'
```

If this is not what you are looking for then, yes, setting the owner is the only way after you create the file using a different user.

**Addendum:** If you want strict security for HDFS access like user isolation so that, only the real owner of a directory/file can access it then, you can probably configure Hadoop to use Kerberos security.

Have a look at these links (please look at the sub-tasks too in the first):

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-4487

and,

http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-auth/Configuration.html

Hope this helps.

Thanks

Comment: I have occasions when doing development on our DEV cluster where I'd like to retain a single owner for the created files rather than see a smattering of users like "bob", "randy" and "jean" which are not actual users on the cluster.  Although not a big deal for a DEV cluster, it looks wonky and there are cases where I have to go back and change the owner to a real user.  If I could just write the file with the desired owner at creation time, I could keep things clean.

Comment: Thanks for adding that detail.  Strict security isn't a requirement at this point.  I was mostly looking to maintain a clean bill of ownership by pinning the ownership of certain files to a known owner.  For example, files only used by application XYZ will be owned by user 'xyz', even in our DEV cluster.

Comment: Yes, then there shouldn't any problem :)